# JS prototype (this) "dot" function without native Object

Tags: javascript

**I'd like to know how to make the second script return same value as the first one (by modifying MyObject), so I don't have to extend native objects.**

Basically, I want to be able to call the function as parameter.functionName() instead of functionName(parameter).

```
Object.prototype.arraySum = function()
{
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
  {
    sum += this[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log([1,2,3,4].arraySum()); /* return: 10 */
```

---

```
function MyObject()
{}

MyObject.prototype.arraySum = function()
{
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
  {
    sum += this[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log([1,2,3,4].arraySum()); /* return: [1,2,3,4].arraySum is not a function */
```

I've looked through many questions here, but I haven't found the answer.

Comment: `MyObject` !== `Array-Object`

Comment: Idk what that means. Array-Object returns NaN and also [] !== Array-Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array literal constructs an `Array` instance, there's no way how you could affect that. So to make this work with `MyObject`, you will need to change the code that invokes it.

A simple solution would a wrapper:

```
function MyObject(arr) {
    this.array = arr;
}

MyObject.prototype.sum = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
        sum += this.array[i];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

```
console.log(new MyObject([1,2,3,4]).sum());
```

There are many other conveivable approaches, but none can change the fact that `[1,2,3,4].arraySum()` is not going to work.

Comment: Thx, I had a feeling that the answer was going to be something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log([1,2,3,4].arraySum())
```

`[1,2,3,4]` is an array and thus inherits from `Array.prototype`, not from `MyObject`. So if you really want to have `parameter.functionName()`, then you have to add `arraySum` function to `Array.prototype`.

But extending native prototypes is not a very good practice.

So you can write your own Array class:

```
function MyArray() {}

MyArray.prototype = new Array(); // all Array method will be available
MyArray.prototype.sum = function() { 
    console.log("My sum function") 
}

var arr = new MyArray(); // it will produce an array-like object
arr.push(1,2,3);
arr.sum() // will log "My sum function"
```

Comment: [1,2,3,4] is an array and thus inherits from Array.prototype, not from MyObject 

--

I think you meant "Object" not "MyObject" and the first script works - I think it is because in javascript arrays are objects -> typeof [] returns "object"

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/nuwanniroshana/2qoko562/

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  this.forEach(function(value) {
    sum += value;
  });

  return sum;
};


var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var sum = numbers.sum();

console.log(sum);

var floats = [1.3, 85.2, 9.33, 1.24, 24.5, 6];
sum = floats.sum();

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: You are extending native object Array -> that's the opposite of what I was asking. Fyi your function also works with Object.prototype.sum = function() ...